# How to connect usb device to Playonlinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I want to run windows installation file on wine which needs to detect my usb device (not a thumb drive) to proceed installation.

I can detect the connection in ubuntu with command "lsusb" but i don't know how to give or share that connection with wine.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Can't you reach to the installer after mounting the device and right clicking the installation file and select open with wine windows loader?

Comment: @Arijit, Hi, for the mounting, is it possible to mount non-memory device to OS with mount command? lsusb gives me bus, device, id.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Wine does not support USB drivers, so you can't connect any USB device to Wine/PlayOnLinux, but Wine does support serial devices, including serial over USB. Check if your device is being recognised as a serial device, e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`. If true, you can create a symbolic link between `/dev/ttyUSB0` and wine dos device file located in `~/.wine/dosdevices/`

> ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 ~/.wine/dosdevices/com1

If it works for you, you can add the command to `Command to exec before running the program` field in your PlayOnLinux app configuration dialog -> Miscellaneous tab.

Comment: It worked with my guitar effect pedal, which can be edited via USB port. I had to plug it and unplug it and compare the results of `ls /dev` to find it. It identified it under `/dev/snd/by-id`. I created the symbolic link as explained, and it worked :)